# Showwordpress user description when user image is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on an existing wordpress site. I am updating a page that displays the users in clickable images. When the image is clicked a dropdown box is supposed to display the users name and description. The problem I am having is, the dropdown box is only displaying the name and description of the last user on the page. The information in the dropdown is not matching up with the image clicked. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the HTML/PHP:

```
<section class="series">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <?php //query for hosts/contributor users
            $cq = new WP_User_Query(array('role'=>'contributor'));

            // User Loop
            if(!empty($cq->results))
            {
                //sort users into current and past by meta field//
                $hosts = $cq->results;
                $current_hosts = array();

                foreach($hosts as $user)
                {
                    $user->sort_num = get_field('order', "user_$user->ID");

                    if(tv_is_host_active($user->ID))
                        $current_hosts[] = $user;
                    else
                        $past_hosts[] = $user;

                }
                usort($current_hosts, 'tv_compare_hosts');


                //display the current hosts
                $row_counter = 0;
                foreach ( $current_hosts as $user )
                {
                    //add rows of four
                    if($row_counter++ % 4 == 0)
                    {
                        echo "<div class='row'\n>";
                    } ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a class="card card-cast" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div class="card-img-cast">
                                <?php if(get_field('profile_picture', "user_".$user->ID)): $image = get_field('profile_picture', "user_".$user->ID); ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"  />
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/thumbholder-medium.png" alt="winchester logo" />
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="card-title"><?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                //add rows of 4
                    if($row_counter % 4 == 0)
                    {
                        echo "</div><!-- end row-->\n";
                    }

            } //end foreach of current hosts


            //cap row if the last row was not full
            if(!($row_counter % 4 == 0))
            {
                echo "</div><!-- end/cap row-->\n";
            }
            ?>

            <?php
        } else { ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 host">
                <p>No hosts found.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
            <?php endwhile;
            endif; //end main loop ?>
        <!-- cast profile dropdown -->
        <div class="container-fluid profile-details hidden">
        <i class="fa fa-times closeBox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="member-name"><?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?></h3>
        <p class=".text-white"><?php echo tv_host_shows($user->ID); ?></p>
        <p class="member-description"><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'description', true); ?></p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="list-inline social">
                    <?php if(get_field('facebook_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Like <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Facebook" href="<?php the_field('facebook_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif;
                    if(get_field('twitter_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Follow <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Twitter" href="<?php the_field('twitter_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif;
                    if(get_field('youtube_channel_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Watch <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Youtube" href="<?php the_field('youtube_channel_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif;
                    if(get_field('website', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="See the website of <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?>" href="<?php the_field('website', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end social link row -->
        </div><!-- end dropdown --> 
        </div><!--end container-->
    </section>

</main><!--end .main-bg -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        initHostsPage();
    });
</script>

<?php

get_footer(); ?>
```

and the jquery function to show dropdown box:

```
function initHostsPage() {
    $('.social').each(function(key, val){
        $(this).children('li').children('a').tooltip();
    });

        //dropdown profile box
    $('.card').click(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('.row');
        var profileDetails = $('.profile-details');
        profileDetails.removeClass('hidden');
        row.append(profileDetails);

        if((profileDetails).is(':hidden')) {
            profileDetails.slideTogle('slow');
        }

        else{
            profileDetails.hide();
        } 
    });

    $(".closeBox").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you use firefox or chrome and check in the console if the user description is being created by your php?

Comment: yes it is created. The problem I'm having is that the php is showing the name and description of the last user only, no matter what user image is clicked.

Comment: Ok. there is a difference between php and javascript. Javascript its frontend and php its backend. I need to know if the backend is correctly creating ALL users and description but javascript is incorrectly SHOWING only the last one

Comment: If I move the <div class ="profile-details"> into the foreach loop, all users and descriptions will display when an image is clicked.

Comment: ok. I asked because the php code seemed right. That means the php is ok, the prblem might be either html or javascript, ill check it

Comment: great, thanks for the help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML/PHP:

```
<section class="series">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <?php //query for hosts/contributor users
            $cq = new WP_User_Query(array('role'=>'contributor'));

            // User Loop
            if(!empty($cq->results))
            {
                //sort users into current and past by meta field//
                $hosts = $cq->results;
                $current_hosts = array();

                foreach($hosts as $user)
                {
                    $user->sort_num = get_field('order', "user_$user->ID");

                    if(tv_is_host_active($user->ID))
                        $current_hosts[] = $user;
                    else
                        $past_hosts[] = $user;

                }
                usort($current_hosts, 'tv_compare_hosts');


                //display the current hosts
                $row_counter = 0;
                foreach ( $current_hosts as $user )
                {
                    //add rows of four
                    if($row_counter++ % 4 == 0)
                    { 
                        echo "<div class='row'\n>";
                    } ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a data-id="<?php echo $user->ID;?>" class="card-cast" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div class="card-img-cast">
                                <?php if(get_field('profile_picture', "user_".$user->ID)): $image = get_field('profile_picture', "user_".$user->ID); ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"  />
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/thumbholder-medium.png" alt="winchester logo" />
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="card-title"><?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?></div>
                            </div> 
                        </a> 
                    </div> 

                    <!-- cast profile dropdown -->
                    <div class="profile-details profile-<?php echo $user->ID;?> hidden">
                        <i class="fa fa-times closeBox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <h3 class="member-name"><?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?></h3>
                        <p class=".text-white"><?php echo tv_host_shows($user->ID); ?></p>
                        <p class="member-description"><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'description', true); ?></p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <ul class="list-inline social">
                                    <?php if(get_field('facebook_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                                        <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Like <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Facebook" href="<?php the_field('facebook_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                    <?php endif;
                                    if(get_field('twitter_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Follow <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Twitter" href="<?php the_field('twitter_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                    <?php endif;
                                    if(get_field('youtube_channel_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Watch <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Youtube" href="<?php the_field('youtube_channel_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                                    <?php endif;
                                    if(get_field('website', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="See the website of <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?>" href="<?php the_field('website', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- end social link row -->
                    </div><!-- end dropdown --> 

                    <?php
                //add rows of 4
                    if($row_counter % 4 == 0)
                    {
                        echo "</div><!-- end row-->\n";
                    }
            } //end foreach of current hosts?>

        </div><!-- end Container -->

            <?php
                } else { ?>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 host">
                        <p>No hosts found.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
                <?php
                }

                ?>
            <?php endwhile;
            endif; //end main loop ?>

    </section>

</main><!--end .main-bg -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        initHostsPage();
    });
</script>

<?php

get_footer(); ?>
```

and the Javascript:

```
function initHostsPage() {
    $('.social').each(function(key, val){
        $(this).children('li').children('a').tooltip();
    });

        //dropdown profile box
    $('.card-cast').click(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('.row');
        var id = $(this).data('id'); //get the card
        var profileDetails = $('.profile-' + id); //get the exact profile
        profileDetails.removeClass('hidden');
        row.append(profileDetails);

        if((profileDetails).is(':hidden')) {
            profileDetails.slideToggle('slow');
        }

        else{
            profileDetails.hide();
        } 
    }); 

    $(".closeBox").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently there were both php and javascript mistakes. In php you succesfully RETRIEVING all users, but only PRINTING the last one, you would need to cast the profile-details inside the loop, but you also need to differentiate each profile-detail so they dont all come out at the same time. And we need to differentiate cards. So to not broke any css I added profile-id class and data-id for the card

```
<section class="series">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <?php //query for hosts/contributor users
            $cq = new WP_User_Query(array('role'=>'contributor'));

            // User Loop
            if(!empty($cq->results))
            {
                //sort users into current and past by meta field//
                $hosts = $cq->results;
                $current_hosts = array();

                foreach($hosts as $user)
                {
                    $user->sort_num = get_field('order', "user_$user->ID");

                    if(tv_is_host_active($user->ID))
                        $current_hosts[] = $user;
                    else
                        $past_hosts[] = $user;

                }
                usort($current_hosts, 'tv_compare_hosts');


                //display the current hosts
                $row_counter = 0;
                foreach ( $current_hosts as $user )
                {
                    //add rows of four
                    if($row_counter++ % 4 == 0)
                    {
                        echo "<div class='row'\n>";
                    } ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a data-id="<?php echo $user->ID;?>" class="card card-cast" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div class="card-img-cast">
                                <?php if(get_field('profile_picture', "user_".$user->ID)): $image = get_field('profile_picture', "user_".$user->ID); ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"  />
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/thumbholder-medium.png" alt="winchester logo" />
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="card-title"><?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                //add rows of 4
                    if($row_counter % 4 == 0)
                    {
                        echo "</div><!-- end row-->\n";
                    }

            } //end foreach of current hosts


            //cap row if the last row was not full
            if(!($row_counter % 4 == 0))
            {
                echo "</div><!-- end/cap row-->\n";
            }
            ?>
             <!-- cast profile dropdown -->
        <div class="container-fluid profile-details profile-<?php echo $user->ID;?>hidden">
        <i class="fa fa-times closeBox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="member-name"><?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?></h3>
        <p class=".text-white"><?php echo tv_host_shows($user->ID); ?></p>
        <p class="member-description"><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'description', true); ?></p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="list-inline social">
                    <?php if(get_field('facebook_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Like <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Facebook" href="<?php the_field('facebook_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif;
                    if(get_field('twitter_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Follow <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Twitter" href="<?php the_field('twitter_profile_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif;
                    if(get_field('youtube_channel_link', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Watch <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?> On Youtube" href="<?php the_field('youtube_channel_link', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif;
                    if(get_field('website', "user_".$user->ID)): ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="See the website of <?php echo $user->data->display_name; ?>" href="<?php the_field('website', "user_".$user->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end social link row -->
        </div><!-- end dropdown --> 
        </div><!--end container-->
            <?php
        } else { ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 host">
                <p>No hosts found.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
            <?php endwhile;
            endif; //end main loop ?>

    </section>

</main><!--end .main-bg -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        initHostsPage();
    });
</script>

<?php

get_footer(); ?>
```

Html set now lets see the javascript. It was selecting any card and retrieving the only profile. Now it will select any card, get its id and retrieve that id profile:

```
function initHostsPage() {
    $('.social').each(function(key, val){
        $(this).children('li').children('a').tooltip();
    });

        //dropdown profile box
    $('.card').click(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('.row');
        var id = $(this).data('id'); //We get the card
        var profileDetails = $('.profile-' + id); //We get the exact profile
        profileDetails.removeClass('hidden');
        row.append(profileDetails);

        if((profileDetails).is(':hidden')) {
            profileDetails.slideTogle('slow');
        }

        else{
            profileDetails.hide();
        } 
    });

    $(".closeBox").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
}
```

Tell me how it goes!

Comment: I'm still getting the same results. Only last user is displayed,scratching my head on this one

Comment: I have it working! Aschab, you were right on track. Just had to move the <div class ="profile-details"> into the foreach 'host' loop. I'll paste my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to help :p sry I didnt answer anything else yesterday, I got to sleep